# Let $f(x) = x^5 + x^3 + x$. Assuming that f is invertible, find $f^{−1}(3)$

Tags: calculus

I'm having difficulty with this question.

Am I supposed to change the function to its inverse form, $x = y^5 + y^3 + y$.

Also what does it mean that $f$ is invertible?

How should I isolate for $y$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Assume that "$f$ is invertible" means that you can start with the assumption that some function $f^{-1}$ with $f\circ f^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ f = {\rm id}$ exists. You don't have to find a term representing it. You only have to find a (by assumption of existence of the inverse, **the**) real number $x$ such that $f(x) = 3$, as:
$$ f(x) = 3 \iff x = f^{-1}(3). $$
Can you see such a number? (Just try)

---

Addendum: If you want to prove the invertibility, you can use that $f$ is monotonically increasing, but the question - as stated - does not tell you to do that. You can just use the invertibility.